# undefined 'items' for nil class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, undefined, checkout

on my e-store website when I try to checkout my cart, I'm getting

```
undefined method `items' for nil:NilClass.
```

Although on the error page

[image: Error]

I know that my cart is there... but when I call it, it gives me nil

[image: toggle session dumb]

Cart Model

```
 class Cart
   attr_reader :items

    def self.build_from_hash hash
      items = if hash["cart"] then
      hash["cart"]["items"].map do |item_data|
      CartItem.new item_data["product_id"], item_data["quantity"]
       end
       else
         []
       end
        new items
     end

    def initialize items = []
     @items = items
    end

    def add_item product_id
      item = @items.find { |item| item.product_id == product_id }
       if item
         item.increment
       else
         @items << CartItem.new(product_id)
       end
    end

    def empty?
      @items.empty?
    end

    def count
      @items.length
    end

    def serialize
       items = @items.map do |item|
         {
           "product_id" => item.product_id,
           "quantity" => item.quantity
         }
       end
      {
       "items" => items
      }
    end

    def total_price
      @items.inject(0) { |sum, item| sum + item.total_price }
    end


 end
```

Application Controller

```
     def initialize_cart
        @cart = Cart.build_from_hash session
     end
```

Cart Controller

```
 class CartsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :initialize_cart

   def add
    @cart.add_item params[:id]
    session["cart"] = @cart.serialize
    product = Product.find params[:id]
    redirect_to :back, notice: "Added #{product.name} to cart."
   end

   def show
   end

   def checkout
     @order_form = OrderForm.new user: User.new
   end
 end
```

Order Controller

```
  class OrdersController
     def create
       @order_form = OrderForm.new(
       user: User.new(order_params[:user]),
       cart: @cart
      )
      if @order_form.save
       redirect_to '/', notice: "Thank you for placing your order."
       @cart.empty?
      else
       render 'carts/checkout'
      end
     end
```

Checkout View

```
 <div class="container-checkout">
    <p class="text-title"> You are checking out the following: </p>
      <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead class="name-table">
          <tr>
            <td> Image </td>
            <td> Name </td>
            <td> Category</td>
            <td> Size </td>
            <td> Item Price </td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      <tbody>

       <% @cart.items.each do |item| %>

        <tr>
          <td><img src="<%= item.product.image %>" width="50px"></td>
          <td><%= item.product.name.capitalize %></td>
          <td><%= item.product.category.name %></td>
          <td><%= item.product.size %></td>
          <td class="price-item"><%= number_to_currency item.total_price %>
        </td>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
      <tr class="total-price total-price-checkout">
        <td class="name-table">Total Price</td> 
        <td class="price-item"><%= number_to_currency @cart.total_price %></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>


<div class="details-user-form">
  <%= form_for @order_form, url: orders_path do |f|%>
  <% f.fields_for :user, @order_form.user do |u| %>
    <p class="text-title">Fill the form with your details</p>
    <p><%= render "orders/errors" %></p>
    <p><%= u.text_field :name, placeholder: "Name" %></p>
    <p><%= u.text_field :email, placeholder: "Email" %></p>
    <p><%= u.text_field :address, placeholder: "Address" %></p>
    <p><%= u.text_field :postal_code, placeholder: "Postal code" %></p>
    <p><%= u.text_field :city, placeholder: "City" %></p>
    <p><%= u.text_field :country, placeholder: "Country" %></p>
    <%= f.submit "Place order", class: "order-btn"%><br>
  <% end %>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

Any idea of why is it doing so? Also because, it was working before.. I don't know why it stopped.

Comment: could you show your entire controller, especially the part that the `@cart` variable is being set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem may be that the `@cart` variable isn't being set in the `OrdersController`. Setting the variable in `CartsController` doesn't make it available globally, as it would only be scoped to the controller that created it, in your case the `CartsController`.

Also, I see that your `Cart` model is more of a virtual model than an `ActiveRecord` model, is that the behaviour you were looking for as I believe `ActiveRecord` already has a lot of the methods you're recreating there.

I'm not totally sure but I think these may be the issues.

**UPDATE**

I think I found your error.

In your `OrdersController` you should have a

```
before_action :initialize_cart
```

That seems to be coming from your `ApplicationController`

Answer (score 1):

If you check your `checkout` method in your `CartController`, you will see that you did not set `@cart`. So when you hit the `checkout` view, it comes to look for the value or `@cart` in this method. Setting it there, like the code below should clear your error.

```
def checkout
  @order_form = OrderForm.new user: User.new
  @cart = # cart object
end
```